# Multiprocessing workers dying prematurely in an odd pattern

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

i have a script that finds all prime numbers with multiprocessing, however half of the spawned workers die very quickly.

i noticed that workers that are about to die early has no I/O operations at all, while others are running normally.

I spawned 8 workers and half die, this is the task manager view:
[image]

This is the function given to workers:

```
import time
import multiprocessing


def prime(i, processes, maxnum, primes): 

    while maxnum >= i:

        f = False

        if i <= 1:
            i += processes
            continue

        else:
            for j in range(2, int(i**0.5)+1, 1): 
                if i % j == 0:
                    i += processes
                    f = True
                    break

        if f:
            continue

        primes.append(i) # append if prime.

        i += processes
        # increment by number of processes, example: p1 (i =1) p2 (i=2) 
        #up to i = processes, then all jumps by num of processes, check for bugs
```

and here is the main, in which workers are spawned:

```
def main():
    start = time.monotonic()
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    primes = manager.list()
    maxnum = 10000000
    processes = 8
    plist = []

    for i in range(1, processes + 1): # adds each new process to plist

        plist.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=prime, args=(i, processes, maxnum, primes,)))

    for p in plist: # starts the processes in plist and prints out process.pid
        p.start()
        print(p.pid)


    [p.join() for p in plist]

    print("time taken: " + str((time.monotonic() - start) / 60) + ' mins')
    print(plist)

    print(sorted(primes))  #unsure how long does the sorting takes


if __name__ == "__main__": # multiprocessing needs guarding. so all code goes into main i guess
    main()
```

Here are the processes state after 5 seconds of starting:

```
[<Process(Process-2, started)>, <Process(Process-3, stopped)>, <Process(Process-4, started)>, <Process(Process-5, stopped)>,
 <Process(Process-6, started)>, <Process(Process-7, stopped)>, <Process(Process-8, started)>, <Process(Process-9, stopped)>]
```

What i find unusual here is there is a pattern, for each spawned worker the next dies.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening, but almost no odd numbers are primes. Is that indicative for what's happening here?

Comment: What's with this line here: `for j in range(2, int(i**0.5)+1, 1): processes.`

Comment: @JHBonarius im not sure i understand the question, when i wrote odd in the question, i meant the behavior is odd. which is my mistake, i corrected the ambiguity.

Comment: Sorry i mixed up odd and even numbers. Language barrier Haha.  What I meant is, there is only one even prime number,  2. All the even processes keep running, while the odd ones die. That might be related?

Comment: @loa_in_ if you were asking about what it does,  j runs from 1 to the current root of i, checks if i % j == 0, if it is true, then its a not prime number. if about ```processes.``` specifically,  its a left over comment that wasn't copied correctly.

Comment: @JHBonarius You're actually right, since as per pattern, p1, p3, p5, p7 are always alive, meanwhile p2, p4, p6, p8 tend to die faster and has no I/O operations. Thank you so much.